# Getting the Vowel Square

Tags: code-golf, matrix

**Challenge**

You will create a function which takes a matrix filled with letters from the alphabet and determine if a `2x2` square composed of vowels exists.

- If a 2x2 square of vowels is found, your function should return the top-left position (row-column) of the square.
- If no 2x2 square of vowels exists, then return the string `"not found"`.
- If there are multiple squares of vowels, return the one that is at the most top-left position in the whole matrix.

**Rules**

- Matrix must be at least `2x2`
- Matrix can only contain letters from the alphabet
- Input can be a String, where each line is separated by `\n`, `,`, `.`, `\t` (`\n` means `line break` and `\t` TAB) or an array of strings.
- Vowels are `a e i o u`.

**Example**

Given `["abcd", "eikr", "oufj"]`

```
a   b   c   d
e   i   k   r
o   u   f   j
```

Output: `1-0`

---

Given `["gg", "ff"]`

```
g   g
f   f
```

Output `not found`

---

**Test Cases**

**Given `["asd", "qie", "euo"]`**

```
a s d
q i e
e u o
```

Output: `1-1`

**Given `["aqrst", "ukaei", "ffooo"]`**

```
a   q   r   s   t
u   k   a   e   i
f   f   o   o   o
```

Output: `1-2`

**Given `["ghsdfhsd", "sdfgsdff", "sdfgsdfg"]`**

```
g   h   s   d   f   h   s   d
s   d   f   g   s   d   f   f
s   d   f   g   s   d   f   g
```

Output: `"not found"`

- Consider the examples as test cases as well

### Update

- If you are going to use 1-based index, please clarify it in your answer.

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes win.

Comment: `If there are multiple squares of vowels, return the one that is at the most top-left position in the whole matrix.` What should happen with that test case : `[[p,d,e,o],[w,v,a,i],[e,u,n,c],[e,e,w,v]]` ?

Comment: @Therandomguy You will take the one that is at the most top-left, so first check the top and then the left. The result in that test case would be `0-2`

Comment: I'd recommend relaxing the return if nothing is found to either a false value or an impossible value, rather than a string

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I phrased my question poorly; can we consistently take only uppercase letters or only lowercase letters in the matrix?

Comment: @Giuseppe. Yes. Sorry, i misunderstood the question.

Comment: Having to return an index pair *or a string* makes this unnecessarily cumbersome in strictly typed languages.

Comment: Agreeing with Dennis, returning any falsy value would seem reasonable.

Comment: This challenge is taken from [coderbyte](https://coderbyte.com/editor/guest:Vowel%20Square:JavaScript), which is not allowed.

Comment: @Laikoni [It's allowed to take the challenge from somewhere else and rewrite the statements](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14841/whats-the-ppcg-policy-on-originality-of-content). Although {@}OP you should link to the source.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 121 bytes

```python
import re
s=input()
w=s.find(',')
v='[aeiou]'*2
m=re.search(v+'.'*~-w+v,s)
print m and divmod(m.start(),-~w)or'not found'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcy7DcMgEADQnimQm4MYU7hnkigFCiCjCI4cHyuNVyd@A7zyawfmfc6YClLj5Fk1MZfehGSnqTrE7AQokGwYeFofsb/gsbNkyOvqLb0PMVbQ8Li2cx2qSlYo5sYTt9lxF0dCJ5KuzdJ9qu06JRJkbDxgzw7mXOyXalP9c@8qBERc/g)

I feel like I don't get to use `divmod` often in Python, haha.

Takes input like `"aqrst,ukaei,ffooo"`.

### Explanation

We compute the width **w** of the matrix by finding the position of the first `,`: in this case, that's 5.

Then, we build the regex `[aeiou][aeiou]....[aeiou][aeiou]` with **(w − 1)** dots: to match vowels on the next row, we skip (one row − 2 letters + 1 comma) = **(w − 1)** characters we don't care about.

To turn `m.start()` back into coordinates, we `divmod` by **(w + 1)** (minding the comma).

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>89</s> 88 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @RickHitchcock*

Takes input as a comma-separated string.

```javascript
s=>~(k=s.search((v='[aeiou]{2}')+`.{${(w=s.search`,`+1)-2}}`+v))?[k/w|0,k%w]:'not found'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1NDoIwGET3nsIQTdtQUFmaVA9CSGjoj1jSTyiFBeLVaze6MC5eZpJ5ydz5xF0ztI8xsyBkUCw4dnlhw1zuJB@aG8YTQyWXLfhqKVZE0jpfdguev0ZN6/REsmJd63Qi5Fqaw/w8UrOfqzOyMG4VeCtQaMA66GTegcYKJ9wJ2reSSg8JIZvftR/cSL2Jx1QpgH@OvjmhIjSGjqhP0VEObw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>143</s> <s>132</s> <s>130</s> 129 bytes

- Thanks to [musicman523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69054/musicman523) for golfing eleven bytes; golfed `{m[y][x],m[y][x+1],m[y+1][x],m[y+1][x+1]}` to `{*(m[y][x:x+2]+m[y+1][x:x+2])}`.
- Thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs), golfed `{...}<={*"aeiou"}` to `{...}<{*"aeiou"}`; using the fact that five vowels do not fit into four cells.

```python
lambda m:([(y,x)for y in range(len(m)-1)for x in range(len(m[y])-1)if{*(m[y][x:x+2]+m[y+1][x:x+2])}<{*"aeiou"}]+["not found"])[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU5LDsIgEN17CsIKrCZWd0ZPgizQMhTbMkpL0sZ49gptjKaLybx5v8xj6Ep0hxHOl7FWzbVQpDkywYZNzwE9GYh1xCtnNKu1Yw3f5hPfL3gxyCRZeK2nQ/THPtvLLOIs/178fXqtqdIWA33LTFCHHQEMrqCSi50cH966jgETVF1vBd0Qqm3l08YA92jiq5/FmCQALGjVTsGn1VM@4FJ/@rZLUqjiJ3MF4tJlyraAcq6KyMSBP2ySffwA)

Comment: Also another interesting but longer solution, but worth posting in case it inspires someone else: [Python 3 139 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY7BDsIgDIbvPgXhBNlMnN5MfBLkgBtluI1OBsn29BNmjGaHpn///2vTcQktussKt/vaq@HRKDJcmWBLOXNATxZiHfHKGc167djAj9XmzztfLDJHFojqe1anlCptMdIM55FkRMzXuTjLIumi@k5cFoI6DAQwuoZKLk5yHb11gQETVD3qhpaEatv53DHCM0H88EOMyQHAzlbTtviyetuPuM9ffgo5il369XMCcU@Zdmqg/ZxKyqSCP20yvr4B)

Comment: @musicman523 Thanks; when using Python 3, one can also use the splat operator on strings: `{*"aeiou"}`.

Comment: You can use `<` instead of `<=` as the 2x2 square will never contain all vowels

Comment: @ovs Wow. true.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, 156 bytes

```java
m->{for(int i=0,j;++i<m.length;)for(j=0;++j<m[i].length;)if((m[i][j]+m[i][j-1]+m[i-1][j]+m[i-1][j-1]).matches("[aeiou]+"))return i+"-"+j;return"not found";}
```

1-indexed output.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##rVFBbsMgELz3FStOIMdWenbSHzSXHi0fCAYMMZAYSFVFfrtL7DTtwa1UKRKwuzOI2Vk0PdNcN4eRddR7eKXKXp4AlA28F5Rx2F1LgLfQKyuB4Tmp6qoGQ8rEDWmn5QMNisEOLGxhNPnLRbgep3dAbdcrXWaZ2pii41aGtiRXTm/XCdUbU6n6TiiB8RWodJ3NMX@eshRu2JSlgxSGBtZyj1FFuXKxzhAhPQ@xt6AylKNMl3OJrAsgXLQNKoexnDs@xn2XOr41fnaqAZPs3x1ScrP@4QM3hYuhOCYmdBbbgmHL3@F7GPNVAET3rEGFP3YqYITI6gvn6tAv4S4K/QOf4IFMk/2vtJRLAkI86HnqF42dFF/0G92jdE@9D0sS8ZC@fdmyc49Sl61vRLtsPTEybfEHJ39pY3gaxk8)

```java
m->{                           // Method with String-matrix input and String return-type
  for(int i=0,j;++i<m.length;) //  Loop over the rows, skipping the first
    for(j=0;++j<m[i].length;)  //   Inner loop over the columns, skipping the first
      if((m[i][j]+m[i][j-1]+m[i-1][j]+m[i-1][j-1])
                               //    If four characters in a square appended to each other,
         .matches("[aeiou]+")) //    are only vowels
        return i+"-"+j;        //     Return the 1-indexed output
  return"not found";}          //  Return "not found"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 26 bytes

```
e€€ØcaƝ⁺€T€µT,FZḢȯ“¤Ø#"ȯ"»
```

Indexing is 1-based.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/1UdMaIDo8Iznx2NxHjbuA7BAgPrQ1RMct6uGORSfWP2qYc2jJ4RnKSifWKx3a/f9wO1D6//9oLoVopcSk5BQlHQWl1MzsIhCdX5qWpRSrA5JKTwcJpKVBuYnFYIWFmalg9aX5MPHCouISkFBpdmJqJkRLfj5MNj2jOCUtA6IVyEoH4jQkdjpUWUFKaj5IuLwsMRNifF4ymE4tLwMpiQUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 82 bytes

```
(.*¶)*?(.)*?[aeiou]{2}.*¶(?>(?<-2>(.))*)[aeiou]{2}(.|¶)*
$#1-$#3
^[^-]*$
not found
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fQ0/r0DZNLXsNPSARnZiamV8aW21UCxLVsLfTsLfRNbIDymlqaSIkNfRqQHq4VJQNdVWUjbniouN0Y7VUuPLySxTS8kvzUv7/rwAA) Explanation:

```
(.*¶)*?
```

Match an optional number of rows which are stacked into capture group 1.

```
(.)*?
```

Match an optional number of columns which are stacked into capture group 2.

```
[aeiou]{2}
```

Match two vowels.

```
.*¶
```

Match the rest of the line.

```
(?>(?<-2>(.))*)
```

Match an equal number of columns on the next line, which are stacked into capture group 3, as the matching empties the capture group 2 stack.

```
[aeiou]{2}
```

Match two more vowels.

```
(.|¶)*
```

Match the rest of the input.

```
$#1-$#3
```

If there's a match, replace the entire input with the number of rows and columns matched.

```
^[^-]*$
not found
```

If the input doesn't yet contain a `-` then the match must have failed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 35 bytes

```
FḟØcṆ
ZÇ€T,€
ṡ€2ṡ2ç"JṖFḣ2Uȯ“¤Ø#"ȯ"»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/t4Y75h2ckP9zZxhV1uP1R05oQHSDB9XDnQiBlBKSMDi9X8nq4cxpQ4WKj0BPrHzXMObTk8AxlpRPrlQ7t/g/kJiYlpwCp1MzsIiCVX5qW9ahhrg6QmZ4OJNLSoLzEYpCqwsxUkNrSfJhoYVFxCZAuzU5MzQQrz8@HyaVnFKekZYC1ARnpQJyGYKZDFRWkpALVzykvS8wEG5yXDKJSy8uA8mAP/QcA) (comes with test-suite)

Way too long, but I guess it'll improve. Uses 1-based indexing.

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 73 bytes

Prompts for character matrix input:

```
z←,(,r)/(⍴r)⊤(⍳⍴,r←<⍀<\(2^/m,0)×2^⌿(m←⎕∊'aeiou')⍪0)⋄z,(~×⍴z)↑⊂'not found'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 134 bytes

```python
f=lambda m,i=0,y=0:m[i+1:]and(m[i][y+1:]and(set(m[i][y:y+2]+m[i+1][y:y+2])<set('aeiou')and(i,y)or f(m,i,y+1))or f(m,i+1))or'not found'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/LboQgFN3PV9yQGCAyjdqkC1Ob9DuMC6aIMqPgAC78egs6mqYL4BzO48K0@N7oYl1lNfDxJjiMTFUZW6qsHGuV5mXDtSABNvVyMNf61025pEWTbsaD0c8oY94qM2Ma7Yot1FiQJFSzUEJPtmOsjQdpZi3wKoPkGVhQGkiN@O1HIAaoVQ8bTzPLO2oYkJxBRimLnq6LipTxHp1VaBe52/JP1W41sznS@SvNn9b5qM2P8OS9yZjTVhxDeidkv5cF1IUl/@Du//DyAjBZpT3g5Pr@4eD6BYnFkAAJ35PEUxoc3LnW@o1CVYG9XLbMvgP6HgbwrfMOpugUb2j9BQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>146</s> 140 bytes

```hs
l x=[0..length x-2]
h x|p<-(!!).(x!!)=([show(i,j)|i<-l x,j<-l(x!!0),all(`elem`"aeiou")[p i j,p(i+1)j,p i$j+1,p(i+1)$j+1]]++["not found"])!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/LTsMwELz3K7ZWJWzloRYkTgkXrnDiGCJqmo3j1LXdxGlz6L@HTQpC1npmd2ZWdiP7IxozTQbGvNimqUGrQgNj8liuCG4@S/h6LVI@0p3zom/cleu4FTedJRSKW4JZ3IpYGsP3aPC0ZxK1G5goPGhoY891tBOEoDdttPvtZ1qWUVQw6wLUbrAVKwVtmk5SW8jhJP37F/DPMXkBP4SP0L1Z2MAIUQQdeqMPMiDwp2dI4O/dAh7okIEBpdjMGuAdyoo0ASkYbbGHPMtAYXh1NqAN/VQw@X2oWMxQHzsCN9QtK1cFU4q6ul647GfHWePsG9x9du76QP1wpC8vVufuimr6qm6WCBFFVf9TtVh8hY5m14vUy0p7mAGvF1b@AA)

#### Explanation

This just generates a list of possible indices, nothing special:

```hs
l x=[0..length x-2]
```

This is just a little helper, that allows quickly accessing the element at `(i,j)` with `p i j` (due to operator precedence it's shorter not to use an operator):

```hs
    p<-(!!).(x!!)
```

This generates a list with all the indices (as strings...) of 2x2 sub-matrices that consist of vowels in order:

```hs
h x|             = [show(i,j)|i<-l x,j<-l(x!!0),all(`elem`"aeiou")[p i j,p(i+1)j,p i$j+1,p(i+1)$j+1]]
```

Now we just need to append the `"not found"` string:

```hs
                  (                                                                                  ++["not found"])
```

This way we can simply retrieve the first element in this list (since it's generated in order and in case of no such indices, there's always the `"not found"` string):

```hs
                                                                                                                     !!0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 61 bytes

```
[:'not found'"_`($#:t)@.(#@,~:t=.4:i.~,)2 2+/@,;.3'aoeiu'e.~]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxC8IwFIT3/opHKzyL8SnVKVIoCE5OriIabJJGoaE2WfvXY1oEOxwc993dK6SECkoOCAy2wKPWBMfL@RSuHFvrQFnf1pjeH8tFxl1e0TKr2MBdSXtuaGB5AcVqU7ED7VBYaTxKGm4hTyCRz8aCAhR9jQw7I5FxlN7in3Sf3kXm30KakSpl7YxrPU3ELGn6WjXTYTQ6So2Vn9cYvg)

### Explanation:

```
   ] a =. 'asd','qie',:'euo'   Let `a` be the first test case
asd
qie
euo
  'aoeiu'e.~] a        creates an equality table between the input and the vowels
1 0 0
0 1 1
1 1 1

2 2<;.3'aoeiu'e.~] a      2 2 u ,. 3 x splits the table into 2x2 overlapping windows
┌───┬───┬─┐
│1 0│0 0│0│
│0 1│1 1│1│
├───┼───┼─┤
│0 1│1 1│1│
│1 1│1 1│1│
├───┼───┼─┤
│1 1│1 1│1│
└───┴───┴─┘
```

I need to check if all the 4 chars are vowels, so I add the numbers 
(reduce with addition `+/` the flattened list):

```
    2 2+/@,;.3'aoeiu'e.~] a
2 2 1
3 4 2
2 2 1
   (t=.4:i.~,)2 2+/@,;.3'aoeiu'e.~] a   flattens the list, finds the first 
4                                        occurence of 4 in it and saves it in `t`
```

If 4 is not found J returns the length of the list. That's why I compare the result
    with the length of the flattened list:

```
   (#@,~:t=.4:i.~,)2 2+/@,;.3'aoeiu'e.~] a    (0 means not found; 1 - found)
0

u`v@.y     '@.' is 'agenda' - checks the value of y and uses it as an index to the
train of verbs on the left. 0 > u; 1 -> v and so on.
```

If `0`, it simply returns 'not found'
If `1`, finds the position by converting the index to a pair of numbers in a number system
    denoted by the size of the input `$#:t`:

```
  3 3#:4          (t is the index of 4, #: convert to antibase, the base is  
1 1               the shape of the table, $)
```